# Upper bound on the sum of the smallest non-zero eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-theory

Let $\mathcal A := \{ A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n \} \subset \Bbb R^{d \times d}$ be a set of symmetric and positive semidefinite matrices.

For a matrix $A_k \in \mathcal A$, denote its (real) eigenvalues by $\lambda_i (A_k)$, ordered such that

$$\lambda_i (A_k) \geq \lambda_{i+1}(A_k)$$

for $i \in \{1, 2,\dots, d-1 \}$. Hence, $\lambda_{1}(A_k)$ and $\lambda_{d}(A_k)$ denote the largest and smallest eigenvalues of $A_k$, respectively. For each matrix $A_k \in \mathcal A$, let $r_k := \mbox{rank}(A_k)$. Thus, the smallest non-zero eigenvalue of $A_k$ is $\lambda_{r_k}(A_k)$. We also have that

$$\mbox{Range} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n A_k \right) = \mathbb{R}^d$$

or, equivalently,

$$\mbox{rank} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n A_k \right) = d$$

I am trying to find an **upper bound** on

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_{r_k} (A_k)$$

in terms of the smallest eigenvalue of the sum of matrices, $\lambda_d \left( \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n A_k \right)$.

---

#### Observations

I would like to obtain something like the following inequality for the smallest eigenvalue

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n \lambda_{d} (A_k) \leq \lambda_{d} \left( \sum_{k = 1}^n A_k \right),$$

generalized to the smallest non-zero eigenvalues instead of the minimum one for each of the matrices. I think that the answer should be something like

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_{r_k} (A_k) \leq \lambda_d {}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n A_k \right)\cdot \max_{k\in[n]}\lambda_{r_k}(A_k),$$

but I am not sure about it and I don't know how to prove it. Any help would be really appreciated.

---

#### Example

As a simple example think of the case in which

$$ A_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad A_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

In this case my bound holds since $\lambda_1(A_1) = 1$, $\lambda_1(A_2) = 1$, and $\lambda_2(A_1+A_2) = 1$.

Comment: Do you have tried the very special case that additionally the matrices are diagonal matrices (of course these commute). Which estimation is of interest to you for this special case?

Comment: I added an example at the end of the question @DieterKadelka. I am in general interested in the case in which $\text{Range}(\sum_{n=1}^N A_n) = \mathbb{R}^d$. I think in that case the bound (or a similar one) should hold.

Comment: If I may ask, why did you delete the question on Math SE?

Comment: didn't get any satisfactory answer there. So I thought it was more a research oriented question.

Comment: I was referring to the smalles eigenvalue of the sum matrix $(\sum_{n=1}^N A_n)$

Comment: Your conjectured inequality is not homogeneous, thus it can not hold. In general it is very much possible that the minimal non-zero eigenvalues of all matrices are large but the minimal eigenvalue of their sum is small. Consider the projections onto close subspaces (for example, two projections to close lines on the plane).

Comment: Upper bound @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: @FedorPetrov the fact that the minimum eigenvalue of the sum of the matrices should be (strictly) positive comes from the fact that $Rank(\sum_{n}A_n) = d$, but I would like to have a quantification of this in terms of the smallest non-zero eiganvalues of the other matrices

Comment: I see what you would like to have. My point is that it is not possible without further assumptions because of the following example: take two lines $\ell_1,\ell_2$ on the plane with a small angle $\delta$ between them. Let $n=2$ and $A_1,A_2$ be projections to $\ell_1,\ell_2$. So $r_1=r_2=1$ and $\lambda_1(A_1)=\lambda_1(A_2)=1$. Then $\lambda_2(A_1+A_2)$ is positive but small since $A_1+A_2$ is close to $2A_1$.

Comment: I see what you mean, my statement is wrong, but anyway I think there should be a way to upper bound $\lambda_2(A_1+A_2)$, maybe with a different constant than $\max_{k\in[n]}\lambda_{r_k}(A_k),$ in terms of $\lambda_{1}(A_1) $ and $\lambda_{1}(A_2)$. How do you think @FedorPetrov? In your example maybe such constant will be scaling as $\delta$?

Comment: @Apprentice: Please try the special case that $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ in addition commute. In this case you can diagonalize these matrices simultaneously and therefore you only need to compare the diagonal elements (instead of the eigenvalues). Which potential interesting inequalites do you get? You then can immediately exclude some "potentially valid" inequalities, f.i. your observation. Maybe that you get a candidate for a valid inequality. Look at the other comments what is not possible.